# installing xampp on usb flash drive mac/changing xampp install location mac

Tags: php, macos, xampp, google-drive-api, osx-yosemite

I'm looking to install xampp on a flash drive for mac. I am running os x Yosemite. Also the mac installer doesn't seem to let you change the install location, but the windows installer I know has the feature of changing the install location. Is there any way to run xampp off of a usb flash drive on a mac? Can you change the install location from applications to somewhere else? Thank you. I am also using google drive to sync all the files into the htdocs folder. I am not using wordpress or anything like that -- just xampp and google drive. Preferably I would like to not have to install any extensions, but if I have to it is ok.